# Why javascript forEach loop is not iterating complete array with splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I was playing with javascript `.splice()` and `.forEach()` methods, 
the code is working fine, But it is not giving output as expected.

the issue is that `.forEach()` runs for half array and then exits.

what i expect output be is

```
[['Apple'],['Banana'],['Mango'],['Pomegranate']]
```

But output is

```
[['Apple'],['Banana']]
```

I am not able to figure it out that why it is behaving like this. from the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

it says that  `.splice()` method updates array's length property. then it should work fine.

Is there any way to make it work like as expected.

For some reason I just donot want to use `.map()` or any other functions.

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Pomegranate']
const fruitsList = []

function removeArrayItem(item,index){
    let fruit = fruits.splice(0,1)
    fruitsList.push(fruit)
}

fruits.forEach(removeArrayItem)
console.log(fruitsList)
```

Comment: What "reasons" are there for wanting to do this instead of `.map()`, which would be much simpler and more efficient?

Comment: Also the explanation for exactly the behavior you're seeing is right there in the MDN documentation.

Comment: @Pointy i am just trying to understand that, why it is not working with this `.splice()`and `.forEach()`, can you please explain little about it. why it is not working

Comment: Also you asked almost the exact same question the other day.

Comment: yes, but i was still confused that , why this was not working with splice and forEach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is pretty clearly described in [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description), the `.forEach()` method determines the elements that will be involved in the iteration *before* it starts.

If elements are added to the array, they will not be included in the iteration. If elements are removed, subsequent elements will be skipped. Basically there's an internal index used to select each element, so if the array gets shorter, that index cannot be adjusted accordingly.

On top of that, your code is written such that the `.forEach()` callback ignores it's arguments. It always just strips off the first element of the `fruits` array. Thus on the first iteration, you get "Apple", and the array now has just three elements. The next iterated element will be "Mango", not "Banana", but because the code pays no attention to `item` you get the new first element of the source array. After that, the array has only two items, so the iteration terminates.

You would see the exact same effect with this code, which is perhaps clearer because the mechanism is visible:

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Pomegranate']
const fruitsList = []

for (let index = 0, len = fruits.length; index < len; index++) {
  if (index in fruits) {
      let fruit = fruits.splice(0,1)
      fruitsList.push(fruit)
  }
}
```

The `if` test in that loop illustrates an important `.forEach()` behavior: it skips indexes of the array which are empty (that is, which have never been initialized to a value). The calls to `.slice()` remove an element from `fruits`, so after the first two iterations it won't even try to perform any more `.slice()` calls because indexes 2 and 3 will be empty.

The proper way to do this, if it were real code, would be

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Pomegranate']
const fruitsList = fruits.map(function(fruit) {
  return [fruit];
});
fruits = []; // if you really want to empty it out
```

(And an `=>` function would be even more terse.)

Answer (score 0):

Splice modifies the source array.

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or
>   replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

This means that when `splice()` is applied to the array that `forEach()` is iterating over, it is modified (gets shorter), so it has no elements to iterate over after a while.

Comment: Yes this is true and may indeed be the source of confusion here.

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the original array in the wrong way if you see what you have after each iteration is the array that is removed from fruits and you are pushing that array into the new list.

With this approach you will keep indexes intact from getting change during the splice mutation.

```js
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Pomegranate']
const fruitsList = []

function removeArrayItem(item,index){
    let fruit = fruits.splice(index,1,'')
    fruitsList.push(fruit)
}

fruits.forEach(removeArrayItem)
console.log(fruitsList)
```

[https://codepen.io/psyNiiM/pen/JjjNRaJT](https://codepen.io/psyNiiM/pen/JjjNRaJ)